# How can I have multiple instances of a column that itself holds a foreign key reference?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am new to Visual Studio so to start learning it I first of all downloaded a sample available at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ADPNET-Entity-Framework-2d1160cb and started working around it. Since I have fairly good knowledge of VB6 and SQL it did not take much time for me to understand the whole pattern the sample is based on. Had Microsoft given a detail explanation or a walk through of the sample it would have been much easier to understand the basics. However, I somehow managed to work around it and have build a small desktop application in wpf using Entity Framework and MVVM. But a point has come where I have got completely stuck up finding no way out. The problem is as under:

I have two tables. 1 Advocate and 2 Party. Table Advocate would contain names of advocates and would have a primary key. Similarly Party would have names and their respective primary keys.

Then I have another two tables 1. Case and 2 CaseDetail. Table Case would simply hold three columns: 1. CaseId 2. CaseNo and 3. Year. Table CaseDetail would have CaseDetailId as a primary key the CaseId as a Foreign Key. Now what I need is that a particular case could have multiple advocates and multiple petitioners. So the table CaseDetail would have two columns to hold advocateId and PartyId as a Foreign Keys.

If you look at the sample referred above you would not find how to deal with such a case. When I follow the pattern of the sample I get host of design time and runtime errors.

Anyways, after number of trials I have somehow manged to set the EF right but I doubt if it would serve any purpose since I need to have multiple instances of Petitioners and Advocates.

Here is the link to my edmx:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rkarzod1lezdnqs/EDMX.png?dl=0

From the image it can be seen that I have four different foreign keys fldPetitioner, fldRespondent, fldAdvocate and fldSrAdvocate for which I too have navigation property to back track them which have multiplicity 0 or 1. Therefore, in such a scenario would I be able to have multiple instances on these columns?

Therefore, please suggest what strategy should be adopted in a scenario described above while developing WPF application using Entity Framework and MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

I think it sounds like you're trying to use one-to-one relationships where there should be one-to-manys. Take a closer look at the relationship between Department and Employee from your linked MS sample. It results in '1 Department to many Employees'. This puts the DepartmentId against an entry in the Employee table, *not the other way round*, which is what I think you have at the moment. The analogous element from your question would be '1 CaseDetail to many Advocates'.

```
public class CaseDetail
{
    //CaseDetail ID number
    public int CaseDetailId { get; set; }

    //...
    //Any other properties go here
    //...

    //Navigation properties
    public ICollection<Advocate> Advocates { get; set; }

    /* Other collections would be executed similarly:
     *
     * public ICollection<Party> Petitioners { get; set; }
     * public ICollection<Party> Respondents { get; set; }
    */
}

public class Advocate
{
    //Advocate ID number
    public int AdvocateId { get; set; }

    //...
    //Any other properties go here
    //...

    //Navigation properties
    public int CaseDetailId { get; set; }
    public CaseDetail CaseDetail { get; set; }
}

public class AdvocateConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Advocate>
{
    public AdvocateConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(a => a.CaseDetail)
                .WithMany(cd => cd.Advocates);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the MS sample, you must have noticed that while entering data we assign Department to an employee although department to employee relationship is 1 to many. In my case the issue is that I want assign advocates to casedetail although the relationship casedetail to advocate is 1 to many. Here simply imagine a simple billing application where table invoice can be a master table having details in table invoicedetails where we can have multiple products as a foreign key. Considering the scenario please tell me whether or not there can be a derived entity with a navigation property to back track the products?